# Akka Actors unstashAll() with Predicate in Java

Tags: java, akka

I want to use akka.actor.Stash API. Is it possible to use unstashAll(filterPredicate: Any ⇒ Boolean) method with Predicate in Java, if yes can you please give an example code of usage.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered on [akka-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/tRtKDuSpIso) - do not use that method, it's private api (and marked as such).